# Reading JSON into dataframe in R

Tags: r, json, import

For a project I'd like to read a JSON file of 9.3 MB into R and use it as a dataframe. The JSON looks as following:

```
{"id":"xxx"}
{"id":"xxx"}
{"id":"xxx"}
{"id":"xxx"}
.
.
.
```

With the following function

```
dh <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(json_file), collapse = ""))
```

I was able to import it, within my environment it is however shown as a "Large Character (9.3)" and I'm not able to further use it.

**Notes**

Could the handling of the file in said way have anything to do with its size?

First time working with JSON files, please go easy on me.

Thanks for any input that might help/help me get some clarity regarding working with JSON in R.

Comment: I think that might be because your `json` file is just full of just `id`s. What you can try maybe is :- `dh <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(paste(readLines(json_file), collapse = "")))`

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately this just produces ```1 obs. of 1 variable``` in my code ...

Comment: Can you provide a link to the file?

Comment: What about `paste0("[", paste0(readLines(json_file), collapse = ","), "]")` ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. It is an exported file from a certain platform in work, that's the reason why I substituted the ID's and naming convention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> fromJSON(paste0("[", paste0(readLines(json_file), collapse = ","), "]"))
   id
1 xxx
2 xxx
3 xxx
4 xxx
```